# logits and labels must be broadcastable: data augmentation layers makes logits and labels mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to **move all my data augmentation preprocessing over to inside my model**, hence, i have created a preprocessing model and merged it into my Resnet50.

The problem is, my `tf.data` pipeline inputs `batch_size` images to the model, that when fed into the preprocessing pipeline generates: `batch_size * 54` images (54 samples per image), hence, **the label information is not associated to the generated images** and i get the error (batch_size = 16):

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[864,516] labels_size=[16,516]
[[node categorical_crossentropy_1/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at <ipython-input-26-8e524a3a5e0b>:31) ]] 
[Op:__inference_train_function_118686]
```

Any guesses on what should i do to keep run data augmentation on the GPU and associate the labels to the corresponding generated images?

#### Auxiliary Code:

```py
'''
Data augmentation pipeline: (yields 54 images by sample)
Extract 5 random crops + 1 central crop,
Rotate +-45 deg, 
Translate in two random directions, then mirror (vertically)
'''
def preprocessing_model():
  input = keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name="input")
  rescaling = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(input)
  central_crop = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CenterCrop(height=112,width=112)(rescaling) 
  resized_single_crop = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(224,224)(central_crop)

  random_crop = keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomCrop(height=56,width=74)])

  random_crop0 = random_crop(rescaling,training=True)
  random_crop1 = random_crop(rescaling,training=True)
  random_crop2 = random_crop(rescaling,training=True)
  random_crop3 = random_crop(rescaling,training=True)
  random_crop4 = random_crop(rescaling,training=True) 

  crops = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([random_crop0,random_crop1,random_crop2,random_crop3,random_crop4],axis=0)
  resized_crops = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(224,224)(crops)

  rotate_1 = keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=[0.125,0.125])])
  rotate_2 = keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(factor=[-0.125,-0.125])])

  rotated_a = rotate_1(rescaling,training=True)
  rotated_b = rotate_2(rescaling,training=True)

  augmented_images = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([rescaling,resized_crops,resized_single_crop,rotated_a,rotated_b],axis=0)

  translate_1 = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=(-0.25,0.25),width_factor=(0.25,0.25))])
  translate_2 = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(height_factor=(-0.25,0.25),width_factor=(-0.25,-0.25))])

  translated_a = translate_1(augmented_images,training=True)
  translated_b = translate_2(augmented_images,training=True)

  augmented_images = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([augmented_images,translated_a,translated_b],axis=0)
  mirrored_versions = keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('vertical')])
  mirrored_images = mirrored_versions(augmented_images,training=True)
  augmented_images = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([augmented_images,mirrored_images],axis=0)

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input,outputs=augmented_images)
  return model
```

> Merging the preprocessing model into the ResNet50:

```py
def load_and_configure_model(optimizer, loss, metrics, path):  
  model = ResNet50V2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
  transfer_layer = model.get_layer('avg_pool')
  resnet_submodel = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=transfer_layer.output)

  augmentation_pipeline = preprocessing_model()
  augmentation_model_cfg = augmentation_pipeline.get_config() # Get layer configuration dictionary.

  model_config = resnet_submodel.get_config()
  submodel = model_config['layers']
  submodel.remove(submodel[0]) # Remove the previous input layer

  prepr_model_layers = augmentation_model_cfg['layers']
  prepr_model_layers.extend(submodel) # Join both models

  # Replace the previous input layer with the output from the preprocessing model
  # (Connect the preprocessing model to the resnet) 
  output_name = prepr_model_layers[len(augmentation_pipeline.get_config()['layers'])-1]['name'] 
  prepr_model_layers[len(augmentation_pipeline.get_config()['layers'])]['inbound_nodes'] = [[[output_name, 0, 0, {}]]]
  new_model = augmentation_pipeline.__class__.from_config(augmentation_model_cfg, custom_objects={})  # change custom objects if necessary

  # Set back pre-trained weights on new model
  weights = [layer.get_weights() for layer in resnet_submodel.layers[1:]]
  for layer, weight in zip(new_model.layers[15:], weights):
      layer.set_weights(weight)

  for layer in new_model.layers[15:]:
    layer.trainable = False
  for layer in new_model.layers[15:]:
    trainable = ('conv5_block3' in layer.name)      
    layer.trainable = trainable

  transfer_layer = new_model.get_layer('avg_pool')
  class1 = Dense(1000, activation='softmax',name='class_1')(transfer_layer.output)
  class2 = Dense(516, activation='softmax',name='class_2')(transfer_layer.output)
  class3 = Dense(124,activation='softmax', name='class_3')(transfer_layer.output)

  model = keras.Model(
      inputs=[new_model.inputs],
      outputs=[class1,class2,class3],
  )
  if not path == None :
    model.load_weights(path)
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)      
  print(model.summary())
  return model
```

> tf.data pipeline

```py
def train_model(train_path, validation_path, buffer_size, epochs, steps_per_epoch, model):
  train_filenames = get_filenames(train_path)
  random.shuffle(train_filenames)

  validation_filenames = get_filenames(validation_path)
  random.shuffle(validation_filenames)

  dataset_length = 91758  
  train_size =  dataset_length * 0.7
  validation_size = dataset_length - train_size

  batch_size = 16

  AUTO = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
  train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(buffer_size=int(1e+8),num_parallel_reads=AUTO,filenames=train_filenames).cache('/cache/train_cache').map(parsing_fn,num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
  train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
  train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
  train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(AUTO)

  # Create a validation dataset
  validation_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(num_parallel_reads=AUTO,filenames=validation_filenames).map(parsing_fn,num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
  validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size)
  validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(AUTO)
  validation_dataset = validation_dataset.repeat(1)

  validation_steps = validation_size / batch_size # "This ensures that the same validation samples are used every time"
  history = model.fit(x=train_dataset,
                          epochs=epochs,
                          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,                        
                          validation_data=validation_dataset,
                          validation_steps=validation_steps)
  return history
```

Comment: I don't think you should be putting your data augmentation logic "inside" the model. You want to have data normalisation and any other operation that is going to be replicated in the inference step as well into the model (so that, ideally, the user of your model will only need to feed a normal RGB image and the internals of how it is normalized/padded etc are into the model), but data augmentation is training-only.

Comment: I see, it does make sense. The thing is that i need to apply augmentation on training, validation and testing, since this model is only for research purpose im not concerned with usability issues, my main concern is running this on gpu, to save time on colab. Moreover, regarding training-only augmentation, that they made possible to disable some of these augmentation layers during test and validation so i guess that would not be much of a big problem.

Comment: I just don't understand why they made possible to run augmentation within the model if you cant generate more than 1 image.

Comment: I believe the intended use case is to apply some augmentation to the input sample, not generating more data. In keras you don't have access to the labels anymore at this stage, so "generational" data augmentation must happen in the input pipeline, where you can still generate the matching labels.

Comment: Yeah... that is sad but thank you for your time anyway it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Keras layer will have to keep the batch size the same as the input, so it's not possible as a Keras layer.

If you really want to generate multiple images, you would have to do this in the ingest pipeline.

That said, the more common approach is to randomly select one out of the multiple images during each epoch. If you do that, you can keep it as a layer within the model.